# Android: Avoiding two logins to Facebook (SDK and Browser) while integrating a page "like" button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add a LIKE button to my android app that the user can press to like a fan page.
To my understanding, this is not possible because of Facebook security restrictions.

My alternative is to display a Like button using WebView with the "like social html code" provided by Facebook. 
The issue with that approach is that the user will have to re-login to Facebook using the web interface for him to see the like button. That is, after he already logged in using the SDK authentication (which is also a web view).

Is it possible to do all of that using only one login?
How is it that logging in using the SDK does not save the cookies to the default web browser (the SDK uses a web view...) ?

Are there any alternatives to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into your application with SSO. Non SSO(Normal) authentication uses the Facebook application installed on the app. If you do a SSO FB login into your app and simply pass a url to webView for the "Like" feature, I guess it should work because you are using a SSO FB login for the app and pre installed facebook app on the device to handle the webview's FB.

I am hopeful about this. Please share your feedback.